# connection times out when trying to connect to mongodb atlas with python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect to my mongodb atlas cluster but i keep getting timed out as soon as i try to do something with my db.

The db i use was created in mongoshell and also the collection i checked their existence in mongodb compass

## ERROR

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: projekt-shard-00-01-rk7ft.mongodb.net:27017: timed out,projekt-shard-00-00-rk7ft.mongodb.net:27017: timed out,projekt-shard-00-02-rk7ft.mongodb.net:27017: timed out
```

## CODE

```
client = MongoClient("""mongodb://user:password@projekt-shard-00-00-rk7ft.mongodb.net:27017,projekt-shard-00-01-rk7ft.mongodb.net:27017,projekt-shard-00-02-rk7ft.mongodb.net:27017/projekt?ssl=true&replicaSet=projekt-shard-0&authSource=admin""")

    client.projekt.category.insert_one({type : "pants"}).inserted_id
```

Comment: Could you check if you have the IP address you're connecting from whitelisted in your Atlas instance, and there is no client-side firewall preventing you from creating a connection to Atlas?

Comment: my ip address is whitelisted, the client-side firewall might be it i will check on it, thanks for you response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this issue for hours. It's odd that it seems to be a connection issue, but it's not throwing a bad auth or anything, just this timeout. The client object seems to be actually created (I could print its properties). I kept playing around and this somehow worked:

- In the MongoDB GUI, navigate to Database Access
- Add a test user with the same read/write permissions to everything as the initial user created upon setup
- Change the connection string in Python to the new user's username + password
- Run the code

For me it finally connected and inserted successfully. After this, the original user's connection string now worked, so I deleted the test user.

I can't identify the root cause of this issue, but it seems like the Database Users table just needed some kind of action performed on it to refresh and begin accepting user connections.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I solved it back then, however I can't recall how I did it unfortunately. I'm pretty sure it wasnt the way you did it though still thanks for your response!

Comment: wow , it's 2022 this issue still exist and the mitigation still work. lol

Answer (score 7):

SO the problem is with your IP Address,

1. GO to the **Network Access** panel in MongoDB Atlas
2. In the **IP Access List** section, you will find all your IP addresses
3. Click on **edit** tab for the current IP address you are using
4. There change the setting to **ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE**

That's it, it will work!

Comment: I have moved to other location and my IP has changes. So it was no longer in whitelist

Comment: i use 0.0.0.0/0 in Atlas to allow all, but then localhost still fails to connect most of the times, but sometimes it's connectable, how strange

Answer (score 1):

Anybody looking for a solution, if you are trying to access Atlas instance from out in the wild, check the "Network Access" tab, as i think you have to whitelist either all, or specific IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding ?ssl=true at the end of the database URI

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, but because of my ISP doesn't resolve multiple levels of subdomains in Atlas URL

Solution:

- Windows control panel >> Network and Sharing
- Adapter settings
- Right-click on LAN or Wifi >> Properties
- Click IPv4 >> Properties
- Use the following DNS: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4