# Netlify function is not connecting to my MongoDB atlas database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, netlify, netlify-function

Actually I am not really experienced with netlify, I faced a problem in a function, it is really confusing,

I have made a website just for making it behave like an api, and it for now haves one function, which acts like a web service for some website am trying to make, this is the function link:
https://omar-api.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/helpPP-webservice/add

So the code trying to connect to mongoDB atlas, the function when i run netlify dev which is test environment, it does connect to mongoDB to my db and it returns the data successfully, I've made some basic response to just test the database, and it worked on netlify dev the test environment, but when i published it on netlify it no longer work, so it works on the test environment, but when I publish it it does not work.

This is the code:

```
‘use strict’;

const { eventNames } = require(‘process’);
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require(‘mongodb’);

// Functions
const processForm = async function (type, body) {};

//Global vars
const uri = ‘mongodb+srv://:@omar-db.pbwn3ml.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority’; //for mongodb
const mainFnPath = ‘/.netlify/functions/helpPP-webservice/’;
const dbName = ‘omar-db’;
const colName = ‘helpPP-DB’;

// MongoDB setup
// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
    serverApi: {
        version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
        strict: true,
        deprecationErrors: true,
    },
});

//

//

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    const path = event.path; //the called path

    //Setting up mongoDB
    try {
        // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
        await client.connect();
        // Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
        await client.db(dbName).command({ ping: 1 });
        console.log(‘Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!’);

        //Reading the returned html
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        const col = db.collection(colName);

        //Form handle:
        if (path == mainFnPath + 'add') {
              //Checking the method
              // if (event.httpMethod == 'GET') {
              //   return {
              //     statusCode: 500,
              //     body: JSON.stringify({
              //       error: 'Form need POST request',
              //     }),
              //   };
              // }

              //Processing the form

              processForm('add', event.body);

              const query = {};
              const projection = { returnhtml: 1 };

              const data = await col.findOne(query, projection);

              return {
                  statusCode: 200,
                  body: data.returnhtml,
                  headers: {
                      'Content-type': 'text/html',
                  },
              };
        }

    } finally {
        // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
        console.log(‘You are no longer connected to MongoDB’);
        await client.close();
    }

    return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: ‘ERROR! Cant show this page, please click the back button’,
        headers: {
            ‘Content-type’: ‘text/html’,
        },
    };
};
```

the function error is timeout coz there is no connection from MongoDB.

I've asked some devs about it but still not working.

On my netlify dev test the response took 2.5 seconds, but i think when deploying on netlify, the response wont take more that 9 seconds, and the function timeouts on 10 seconds.

Can i just edit the package? or what?

Comment: There is option on mongodb to limit the connection to a certain IP, you can check that. Plus add the catch block and log the error, it could help. `catch(e) {console.log("Error ", e)}`

Comment: Look  at the code, it is all rapped inside a try, but MongoDB does not even response

Comment: I see the code is wrapped inside try catch. mongodb will try to create a connection with the provided URI, if it did not response it will give time out error. But with the above code, we can't determine what the error is. So add catch block and log the error. As I mentioned earlier, check if this is the case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51526142/6932421